# As a module developer, how do I handle outputting user defined strings with regards to translatability?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

A module I maintain is introducing the ability to customize some messaging that is output to users on the site. Up until now, that messaging has been hard-coded and output using the `TranslatableMarkup` class. I'm now allowing these strings to be customized in configuration.

Is it still appropriate to just dump whatever the configured string is into the `TranslateMarkup` class? It seems like I should not do that.

I found this [old core issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/141461) that seems to be related to what I'm discussing, but there's no clear conclusion on what to do.

Comment: "I'm now allowing these strings to be customized in configuration." - Module settings or configuration entities? The latter allow translations via the GUI (Configuration translation), if you defined the strings as type 'label' within the schema file(s).

Comment: @MarioSteinitz Ah, perfect. Yes, thru config entity. Thank you. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.